# Implement smart contract that can spend user's tokens with just one approve

Tags: solidity

I am looking for a way to implement smart contract that can spend user's ETH or erc-20 tokens  with just one approve, without anything else required from user.

**USECASE**

- 1.User approves token spending(usdt for example) he has 10 USDT.
- 2.**WITHOUT USER INTERACTION** our smart contract can transfer this 10 usdt from user to wherever else it is coded to transfer it.
  (This function `spend_user_usdt` should be invoked with either
  something like [chainlink cron job](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-nodes/oracle-jobs/all-jobs) or  manually by contract
  creator.
- 3. Since User already approved token spending it doesn't require anything to do, tokens are transfered from his wallet automatically

I know this is **possible** because sometimes smart contracts get hacked and users have to revoke tokens approval, or their tokens are gone without additional manual confirmation.

But I wasn't able to find decent information on it.

**PS**: Just in case I don't want to write malicious smart contracts - that in not in the zone of my interests. This mechanics could be used to build very interesting projects that simplify user experience in many areas.

Answer (score 3):

This is part of the ERC20 specification.

See here, the `transferFrom()` function. https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20#methods

Users send a transaction to the token contract to `approve` your contract to spend an allowance, the $10 over which your contract would have control.

How your contract exercises that control is entirely an application concern. I see no reason why a chainLink keeper or other external signal couldn't trigger the "approved" contract to take action, spending the user's funds.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So basically just to be sure that we are on the same page: Let's look at USDT. User calls approve function of USDT smart contract with my_contract_address with amount =10$. After this, my contract could without any actions needed for user spend his $10. ?

Answer (score 2):

As Rob Hitchens said, this is an already existing feature of Erc20 tokens. However, i would like to add that you can't do that with ETH, since it's not a token. But you can do this with wrapped eth, and it's the same very simple mecanism.

Comment: hi, thanks for addition, I will add this comment to your answer too: just to be sure that we are on the same page: Let's look at USDT. User calls approve function of USDT smart contract where he specifies my_custom_contract_address and amount =10$. After this, my contract could without any actions needed from user spend his $10 ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: awesome thanks, i will try and let you know

Comment: Thanks, Yann. Yes, ETH is the exception since it's not an ERC20.